# Which 'Design Pattern' is appropriate for a class with a complex (multiple steps) configuration

Tags: oop, class, design-patterns, coding-style

Whenever a setup-wizard is used, then the user answers many different things until the real installation can be started. Comparing this with a class in my current project: I have a class that requires multiple configuration steps. It is not for an installer, but I thought that installer wizard is a good way to explain the required larger configuration functionality.
I am trying to find a good design solution.

My current solution approaches:

1. Flat: I could define one large class with all steps included as methods/functions/properties. Either a few control methods could be added to throw exceptions when calling the wrong methods. It would do its work, but a programmer would be confused seeing so many different methods. (-> he would require more time to understand how it works)
2. Hierarchy: I could create about 3 different classes for each configuration step. Each has its own methods and functions. Finally one class would require an instance of all 3 configuration-classes in its constructor. This would not look too confusing, since only the correct methods are visible in each class. However, a programmer may be annoyed, that a small class requires such a complex preparation, creation of 3 other classes. Maybe nested classes, but I think this would also be a bad coding-style.

**I wonder if someone has already experience with such a problem and can answer this by.. Either providing a fitting design pattern, or some experience/best practices class structures for such problem.**

I have searched for similar questions, have checked some design patterns that may fit, and already provided 2 approach ideas to show in what direction an answer could go. If you think that the answer is not clear enough, please comment/ask about the missing part.

Comment: the problem is there is an infinite possibility of design patterns that can be involved , depending on what your exact requirements are, the exact domain , we dont know them. You should find a project where there is a wizard a read the source code. They usually involve some kind of state pattern.

Comment: If one class has that much to do, this indicates that there is already some design flaw. Can you elaborate on this complex bootstrapping a bit more please? Because if there is already some problem with separation of concerns, you probably will find no golden hammer to turn that into good design.

Comment: @mpm thanks for explaining. I am working with VB.Net/C#, instead of the functionality of a wizard, a class should be easy to use, but this class requires multiple configuration steps. With a state pattern I would be able to change actions for identical method calls, but if the methods change in each step, then I guess I cannot use it. I am defining multiple enums in my current project, then choose which one to access from a database. A method should provide the resulting list of strings(index relevant). After this, the 'configuration' is done, and the class should serve as index lookup-table

Comment: @MareInfinitus my main target is a communication with a database. Since it requires a List of strings (to define which values to access) and allows to acces those values later with the list-index-number, I would like to use a simple enumeration. However, some of those variables exist n times, where n should be changeable for a programmer later. So I think that I need to build a more complex configuration. As 1.step define which parameters from the enum definitions to use, as 2.step get a list of strings from the class, and 3.step ask class for an index from an enum, so i can use enums in code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what is explained in the question and comments, the "single class to rule them all"  approach seems to be no good choice.

Perhaps some kind of strategy pattern is the way to go here.

Instead of a very complicated setup of your single class, you choose from different strategies depending on what your requirements are. If you already know that there
will be about three different things that can happen, make three different strategies.

Lets make an example:
You want to write log data. Perhaps to a file, a database or a webservice.

Then you have only a single dependency to a "LogWritting Strategy" which has
a clearly defined interface, lets say

```
interface ILogWriter
{
    void Write(enum LogLevel, string logEntry);
}
```

Now, in your client code, you depend on that interface and just make calls on the interface. But at runtime, you "inject" a concrete strategy based on your "configuration".

I.e. you just select the suiting strategy and you do not have a complicated bootstrapping of a single class.

Then you use concrete strategies like

```
IDatabaseLogWriter
IFileLogWriter
IWebServiceLogWriter
```

A brief explanation of what strategy is about can be found here: 
[Strategy pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/PatternStrategy.aspx)

**Update**

from the most recent comment I think that both Repository and Mapping patterns can help.

You should consider looking at

[Repository pattern, good explanation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649690.aspx)

[Repository explanation by Martin Fowler (top notch architecture)](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html)

[Metadata mapping](http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/metadataMapping.html)

Comment: repository looks interesting. A Controller class with dataMapping included. But the problem is that such an additional data access layer already exists in my case. Its configuration (a datamapper implemented with numbers representing always the same fields) is not that straightforward, hard to extend. So I am looking for a pattern to make the configuration of the datamapper more easy. Right now, adding a field requires me to change code at three different places inside the mapper. Therefore I want one class that takes care of the configuration, and the class itself should be 'easy' to change.

Comment: Perhaps you want to have a look at http://martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_mapper_pattern Code examples are included in the second link

Comment: Thanks for the recommendations, I checked answered, since you are right, that a well structured datamapper should not have such configuration problems. However, I am using a mixture of factory and builder pattern.